# C++ vector counting each element's occurance

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector of type `vector<unsigned>` and I want to find out how many times each element occurred in this vector.

This vector could be pretty large, so looping through it wouldn't be a good idea I guess.

What would be the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: There's no way to do what you ask without iterating through the entire vector.

Comment: So you wanna do it without iterating through the entire vector. Would you like to use magic instead?

Comment: if you really want to be fast then parallelize the operation. If you have 4 processors divide the vector into 4 parts and process each chunk separately, then consolidate the results. I mean using threads.

Comment: Each element occurs once, though there may be duplicate values.

Comment: What is the possible range of your element values?  To count them, you'll need a map, unordered_map, or another vector.  Iterating through the vector is not necessarily the slow part.  It's finding duplicates that's slow.  Unless your vector is already sorted or your value range allows indexed lookup instead of hashes or trees.

Comment: Can't you change the data structure? For example to keep a sorted vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the vector is already sorted (or at least grouped so identical elements are all together), looking at every item in the vector is unavoidable (and even if it is sorted, unless you expect a lot of duplicates, chances are pretty good that looking at every item will be the preferred method anyway)<sup>1</sup>.

One obvious method would be to walk through the vector, and count element with a `std::unordered_map`:

```
std::unordered_map<unsigned, size_t> counts;
for (auto v : your_vector)
    ++counts[v];
```

Then you can (for example) print out the values:

```
for (auto const &p : counts)
    std::cout << "The value: " << p.first << " occurred " << p.second << "times\n";
```

---

1. If you do (expect to) have lots of duplicates, and the items are ordered, you can use a binary search to find the end of the run of the current value. The theoretical break-even point for this is if the average number of duplicates of a given value is equal to the base 2 logarithm of the overall size, so if the number of duplicates is greater than that, a binary search will require fewer comparisons. A modern CPU gains enough from a predictable, linear access pattern that you'd probably need substantially *more* duplicates of each value (on average) for a binary search to be a win though.

Comment: Ok, this worked, but how? How does it know `size_t p.second` is to be initialized at 0?

Comment: @JAgustinBarrachina: When you use `foo[x]` for a value of `x` that's not in the map yet, it creates an entry with `x` as the key and value-initializes the associated data. For an integer or floating point type, value initialization set it to 0.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't understand how `map` and `unordered_map` work. Here is my stupid method to do it. The benefit of this method is it allows us to sort the element ascendingly and descending by only changing the `*min_element` and `*max_element`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    int min, count;
    std::vector<int> numList = {1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6};

    while (!(numList.empty())){
        min = *min_element(numList.begin(), numList.end());
        count = std::count(numList.begin(), numList.end(), min);
        std::cout << min << " has occurred " << count << " times" << std::endl;
        numList.erase(std::remove(numList.begin(), numList.end(), min), numList.end());
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
1 has occurred 2 times
2 has occurred 3 times
3 has occurred 3 times
4 has occurred 1 times
5 has occurred 1 times
6 has occurred 2 times
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::count`.

Simple to use:

```
std::count(vect.begin(), vect.end(), 3);
```

Comment: This will be highly inefficient. Unless you just want to count the occurrences of one element, you will call this function the "number of unique elements" times.